# Place the Content Text at the center inside the teaching tip

Tags: uwp, alignment, winui

I am using the teaching tip control from WinUi 2.4 in UWP,I want to place the content at the center of the teaching tip.But I anm not able to place the content at the center.I am not providing any title,subtitle.Please find the attached image.Can I make the close icon invisible.

```
<winui:TeachingTip x:Name="ToggleThemeTeachingTip2"
                    IsOpen="True"                        
                    PreferredPlacement="Bottom"
                    PlacementMargin="30"                                 
                    Background="Green" Foreground="White"  
                                   
                    >
                    <winui:TeachingTip.Content>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Text="Content of the teaching tip"></TextBlock>
                    </winui:TeachingTip.Content>
                </winui:TeachingTip>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, this is determined by the style of the `TeachingTip` control template, `TeachingTip` leaves a certain space for the top. You can see the full template definition of `TeachingTip` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/cf949ae34cc213b5e9bba5613cd7ed46985fcecb/dev/TeachingTip/TeachingTip.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is not the cleanest solution, but doesn't take much effort and works pretty well. Just add negative margin to the content element (`TextBlock` in your case):

```xml
<TextBlock Margin="0,-40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Text="Content of the teaching tip"></TextBlock>
```